# Weird handling of nulls by Hive distinct on multiple columns?

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

This query:

```
SELECT count(distinct
field1, 
field2, 
field3, 
field4)
FROM SOME_TABLE
```

returns a different (smaller) count than this query:

```
SELECT count(distinct
coalesce(field1,"null"), 
coalesce(field2,"null"),
coalesce(field3,"null"),
coalesce(field4,"null"))
FROM SOME_TABLE
```

I would expect the results to be identical. Is there an explanation for this?

Answer (score 4):

The reason you're seeing different results is because of two things:

- `COUNT(DISTINCT(...)` only counts distinct values when ALL specified fields are non-null.

  - This is listed in [the documentation](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF), but it's a bit ambiguously worded when there are multiple fields.
- When you coalesce your `fieldn` values, you're saying "when `fieldn` is null, give me the string "null", otherwise give me `fieldn`"

I was recently trying to validate my assumptions on this too, and couldn't find it unambiguously stated anywhere.  But say you've got a table like this (where the nulls below are null value, not string null):

```
-----------------
|field1 |field2 |
-----------------
|foo    |null   |
|null   |foo    |
-----------------
```

Then:

- `count(field1)` = 2
- `count(distinct field1)` = 1
- `count(distinct coalesce(field1, 'bar'))` = 2 ('foo' and 'bar' distinct)
- `count(distinct field1, field2)` = 0 (no combinations where both are non-null)